# Oracle display value before decimal for 0's

Tags: oracle

For exmaple:
select 'A='||(0.22*0.11)||'' as A from dual;
it does return A=.0242
expected A=0.0242`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `to_char` function with desired format mask, then you get

```
SQL> select 'A='|| to_char(0.22*0.11, 'fm999G990D0000')||'' as A from dual;

A
---------------
A=0,0242

SQL>
```

---

As of a "generic" format model: you can't "dynamically" set it, but - if you use `9` instead of `0` after decimal point, you might get what you wanted:

```
SQL> select 'A='|| to_char(88.223*99.112, 'fm999G990D9999999999')||'' as A from dual;

A
---------------------
A=8.743,957976

SQL>
```

- Benefit: it returns result you want
- Drawback: how many `9`s will you have to put in there? You can't tell - set it to the "worst" case you expect (such as 10 of them in my example)

Comment: select 'A='|| to_char(88.223*99.112, 'fm999G990D0000')||'' as A from dual;
Seems rounding value to 4 digits after decimal.  Can we have generic one? expected value = 8,743.957976‬

Comment: Agree, thank you very much for all your efforts on this.  Why ORACLE does truncated preZero when we us || symbol?  If we don't concatenate it gives you the correct value.

Comment: You're welcome. Behavior you describe depends on a tool you use. For example, in SQL*Plus you can use SET NUMFORMAT to format numbers in desired way. Or, GUI tools have their own options.